# PHP json_decode array cannot retrieve numerical index?

Tags: php, json, phpunit

I have an array that is associative that I have decoded from a json `json_decode second value true` and looks like

```
Array (
    [test] => Array
        (
            [start] => 1358766000
            [end] => 1358775000
            [start_day] => 21
            [end_day] => 21
        )

)
```

But for some reason when I do $array[0] I get null? How can I get the array by index? Not by key name?

Comment: You should move the information from your comment into the question so it's clear to others that your array has multiple items in it, and that you're trying to access next and previous items.  If you don't need the info in the key, then Ignacio's answer below should work.

Comment: @Steven if any answers helped, you might want to consider marking one as accepted :)

Comment: Oh don't worry I know how to accept answers lol. I just haven't been on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) will give you all the values in an array with keys renumbered from `0`.

Answer (score 2):

The first level of the array is not numerical, it's an associative array. You need to do:

```
$array['test']['start']
```

Alternatively, to get the first element:

```
reset($array);
$first_key = key($array);
print_r($array[$first_key]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`current`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php).

```
$first = current($array); // get the first element (in your case, 'test')

var_dump($first);
```

Comment: The problem is I also need to get the previous and next keys (which is why I need to access via index.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design . . . your JSON used a key (apparently `test`), which contained a JSON object.  The keys are preserved when you do a `json_decode`.  You can't access by index, though you could loop through the whole thing using a `foreach`.

From your comment, it sounds like you want to access previous and next elements from an associative array.  I don't know a way to do this directly, but a hackish way would be as follows:

```
$testArr = array('a'=>'10', 'b'=>'2', 'c'=>'4');
// get numeric index of the element of interest
$keys = array_keys($testArr);
$i = array_search('b', $keys);
// get key of next element
$nextElementKey = $keys[$i+1];
// next element value
$nextElementValue = $testArry[$nextElementKey];
// get key of previous element
$prevElementKey = $keys[$i-1];
// prev value
$[prevElementValue = $testArry[$prevElementKey];
```

You'd probably want to add some error checking around the previous and next key calculations to handle the first and last values.

If you don't care about the data in the key, Ignacio's solution using `array_keys` is much more efficient.